# Android - switch to activity without restarting it

Tags: android, android-activity, switch-statement

I am programming a chat program for android.

I have the contact list as one activity and the chat windows as a second activity.
I use startActivity to switch to the chat activity, but the chat activity gets reloaded every time. Therefore the screen gets cleared.

Is there a way to switch to a running activity without having to restart it?

```
private Intent myIntent = null;
```

…

```
    if (myIntent == null)
        myIntent = new Intent(HanasuAndroidActivity.activity, ChatWindow.class);

    this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Too complicated. I would use one activity and consider something like ViewFlipper

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to your `Intent`. That will bring the existing activity instance to the foreground if it exists or create a new one if it does not exist.