# What is way to show authorization activity instead of main app activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, task, back, flags

I have need to show autorizationa activity if user not autorized.

I have use Launcher activity (has nohistory flag) with next code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Autorization.isAutorized()) 
    {
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        // add some flags????
        startActivity(newIntent);
    }
    else startActivity(new Intent(this, AutorizationActivity.class));
}
```

When `autorization` are complete, `AutorizationActivity` starts Launcher with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and then `Launcher` starts `MainActivity`, but I have some trubles with backstack. By pressing back in `MainActivity` android shows `AutorizationActivity` again instead to hide task.

What flags I must use to prevent go back to `AutorizationActivity` from `MainActivity`?

Comment: I have remove no history flag and add finish(); after start MainActivity methods. It is correct way?

Comment: may or may not work.. setting flag is the reliable way..

Comment: It is work! Also I have add in AutorizationActivity next code:
 public void onBackPressed() 
 {
  moveTaskToBack(true);
 }

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this , the easiest would be to use the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Just add `android:noHistory = "true"` in the authorization activty.

Also have a look at the following question : [removing an activity from the history stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)

Comment: I can not add this flag to autorizationactivity i.e. it is not one activity, user must have ability go back in avtorization process

Comment: @Nik .. you might want to try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937120/switching-between-activities-in-android/9937281#9937281

Answer (score 0):

try setting flags for AuthorizationActivity in Manifest something like [this..](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).. right now your flag applies only to MainActivity and not the Current Activity.. so set in Manifest instead..