# Android: how to quit an activity without closing it when click on back button?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-background

I have a subActivity that can be open from my mainActivity.

For some reasons, when the user clicks on the back button go back to my mainActivity, I want my subActivity to remain open in background in order to be able to come back for later.

Questions:

- how to avoid to close the subActivity when the user clicks back ?
- how to come back to the mainActivity without restarting it ?
- how to come back later to my opened activity without re-creating it completely ? (just want to bring it to front)

Thanks !

Comment: Don't finish your activity just change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On you **subActivity** `onBackPressed()` add this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     Intent i = new Intent(SubActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

    startActivity(i);
}
```

on **mainActivity** :

```
  private void openSubActivity() {        

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SubActivity.class);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks but how to come back to the mainActivity without restarting it ?

Comment: Ok, probably found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688099/android-switch-to-activity-without-restarting-it for this last point

Comment: I modified your answer with the solution ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

override `onBackPressed()` and remove `super` from it then try opening the activity which you want to open from there for ex-

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
 // your code
    }
```

and with the help of different activity launch modes you can achieve it